# cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to type Test<char>, why?

Tags: c#, char, type-conversion, console-application

I am making a sample program for later students who take C# for their independent study. I thought I understood `<T>` but apparently I'm lacking some magical secret that allows me to use it to its full extent.

When I try to make a variable it works fine:

```
 static Test<char> c = new Test<char>('n');
```

As you can see it's instantiated and everything.

Now when I go to assign it to a different value via `Console.Read()` then it gives me the error:
Cannot implicitly convert type `'char'` to `'ConsoleApplication1.Test<char>'`

I have tried both :

```
c = (char)Console.Read();
```

and:

```
c = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

and even:(I know it's dumb to do this, but I was getting annoyed and wanted to see if it would work)

```
c = (char)Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

So, I am thoroughly confused as to how to continue. Help please.

EDIT: 
Current Constructors in `Test` class:

> ```
>     public Test() { }//empty constructor
>
>     public Test(T obj)
>     {
>         variable = obj;
>     }//filled constructor
> ```

Comment: Well in the first case you're calling the constructor. In the other cases you're not. Is there any reason why you're not using `c = new Test<char>((char) Console.Read())`?

Comment: I am not trying to make a new variable at that point so why would I call the constructor again?

Comment: Because you're trying to create a new *instance* of `Test<T>`. I think you're confused about the relationship between variables and constructors.

Comment: Since this is a demo program for other students to use in the future I will try to use both at seperate occasions.
Note: I am learning in the process, so I find this very fun. =D

Comment: Sure, you'll definitely need to use both constructors and variables. But your comment of "I am not trying to make a new variable at that point so why would I call the constructor again?" suggests that you have fundamentally misunderstood the purpose of calling a constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess I may have misunderstood. My understanding of constructors is that they are used for instantiating a new instance of a variable. Is that false?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely false. They're used to create a new instance of a *type*. The result of a constructor call *may* be used as the initial value when declaring a variable, but it certainly doesn't have to be.

Comment: Well that is certainly eye opening...

Comment: this works well I will use this in the future, but the implicit type converter looks more extensive and maybe more uses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test<char>` isn't a `char`. It's a new generic type (`Test<T>`) that (presumably) does something with the object of the type argument (i.e. `T`) provided.  In your example, you've stated you want to use the `char` type as the type argument for this generic type.

Imagine you have a property on `Test<T>` that is of type `T`:

```
class Test<T>{
    public T MyTypeValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create an new instance of this generic type, and assign the property the instance of the thing your trying to get (in this case, the console read):

```
static Test<char> c = new Test<char>(){ MyTypeValue = 'n'};
```

Since `MyTypeValue` is of type `char` by way of the generic type's `T` type argument, you can assign an actual `char` to it, but just not to `c`.  That is, without implementing some other conversion method which is what it appears @Austin is suggesting.

Comment: I am creating the variable as global so I believe it would be `static Test<char> c = new Test<char>{ c.MyTypeValue = 'n'};`

Comment: The `{ }` syntax after the constructor is an example of an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).  You don't include the instance name you are modifying.  It's assumed to be the new instance.  (Also, I edited my response: constructor call was missing parens.)

Comment: The `{ }` syntax was not what I added the formatter must have changed it when I posted.I actually had those as parenthesis.